# Visual Studio Community 2015 Installation stuck on creating a system restore point

Tags: installation, restore, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I tried to install the new Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition but unfortunately without success because the installation gets stuck on creating a system restore point.

What I did to solve the problem:

- checked if enough space on disk
- started installation as administrator
- adjusted the maximum disk space used for system protection (4GB)

Do you know other possible solutions I could try to solve my problme?
Ty

Comment: Are you able to create a restoration point manually currently?

Comment: @Ramhound I never created a restoration point manually.
But is there any way to get over this step and continue with the installation?

Comment: I am asking if you can create a restoration point in order to rule out several dozen reasons connected to the inability to do so.  When you answer my *simple* but *important* question I will be continue my research into your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound i tried it and yes I am able to create a restoration point manually

Comment: I have not installed VS in awhile.  The restoration creation process is before/after the installation process begins/ends?  Can you verify the hash of the .ISO your using is correct?

Comment: I had VS2013 Pro hang on the system restore point.  I ended up cancelling the install and after rebooting tried it again.  On the 2nd attempt I ran the install program as administrator and that got the installation working.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had the same problem during installation VS2015 on Windows 10.

I solved the problem by killing the `svchost.exe` process that blocked the installation:

1. Go to the **Task Manager details tab**
2. Find `vs_community.exe`
3. Open the **Analyze** wait chain,
4. Check `svchost.exe` and kill it.

It will stop creating the system restore point, but will resume the installation.

Comment: In my case it was csc.exe

Comment: Same solution works when installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 5. Just look for `VS2015.5.exe` instead.

Comment: In my case it was csc.exe too, ty!

Comment: In my case it was dllhost.exe :)

Comment: I experienced it when installing VS2015 Update 2 and it worked!

Comment: For the ones who experienced -almost- the same during last step of installation (configuring System) on Windows 10 : Check Task Manager as @Ik suggests but in this case ensure there is no working VS2015 update1 parts { All my instances closed before update-2 installation..everything went fine but "configuring System" step waits over 8-9 hours..When i check and cancel update1 tasks finishes installation..Hope this helps }

Comment: I experienced a different scenario. Analyze Wait Chain only revealed two vs_community.exe with different PIDs (1240 & 6421). Ordered Details by PID and found the nearest PID svchost.exe (1280), ended that and it continued installation

Comment: In my case it was dllhost.exe

Comment: There is no details tab in Win7

Comment: Killing this task forced a blue screen but after the restart, the updater finally moved passed the restore point step. I don't know what to think of this...

Answer (score 6):

Try to disable any antivirus running on your machine. 
It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

The current version of AVG Free antivirus is incompatible with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

1. It does not allow Visual Studio to be installed on the computer. It gets stuck at "Creating restore point". Visual Studio installs perfectly when AVG is turned off.
2. Any code compiled in "Release" mode targeting x86 platform/environment (in project properties) does not compile. It compiles successfully when AVG is turned off.

I posted the issues in AVG support forum but no one responded.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.
I'm using 2 Anti-Viruses AVG Internet Security, Avast Internet Security.
I tried to stop AVG Firewall and stop Avast until shutdown.
And It worked. Installation success

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8 the above is almost right.  Analyze chain yielded no svchost.exe.  However, if you're only running the installer just look for the svchost.exe that is the biggest memory hog, cross your fingers, kill it.