# Do You Need Visual Studio With Unity?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Im trying to install Unity 5.3.1 and Visual Studio is stuck on creating system restore point. I am running Windows 8.1  What should i do?

Comment: you don't Need visual studio, but I would certianly Want visual studio if I were to write code for unity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MonoDevelop instead, but Visual Studio is often seen as a superior IDE in many ways, and certainly my preference.

I'm not sure how long you've left it for to ascertain that it is definitely stuck, but if you have to cancel the installation there is an alternative.

I have found a similar question to yours, although in different circumstances, that may [help](https://superuser.com/questions/946227/visual-studio-community-2015-installation-stuck-on-creating-a-system-restore-poi)